# How can I have a different enumeration of values for an element based on the value of an attribute in xsd

Tags: xsd

For example I'm looking for a way to validate this XML

```
<A>
    <B Type=”apples”> <!-- This can be 1, 2, or 3 --></B>
    <B Type=”oranges”> <!-- This can be 4, 5, or 6 --></B>
    <B Type=”grapes”> <!-- This can be 7, 8, or 9 --></B>
</A>
```

Where apples, oranges, and grapes are the only types of Type attributes available.  If the Type attribute is "apples" then the  element can have a value of 1, 2, or 3, but **CANNOT**  have a value of 4 through 9.

The closest solution I could come up with was this

```
<xs:element name="A">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="B" type="BType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- BType -->
<xs:complexType name="BType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="BPossibilities">
            <xs:attribute name="Type" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="apples" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="oranges" />
                        <xs:enumeration value="grapes" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- BPossibilities to enumerate different possible B values -->
<xs:simpleType name="BPossibilities">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="2" />
        <xs:enumeration value="3" />
        <xs:enumeration value="4" />
        <xs:enumeration value="5" />
        <xs:enumeration value="6" />
        <xs:enumeration value="7" />
        <xs:enumeration value="8" />
        <xs:enumeration value="9" />    
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The issue is that this would allow

```
<B Type="apples">9</B>
```

Comment: Are you using XSD 1.1? If so you can do it easily

Comment: I am using 1.0 unfortunately. This is actually something I'm trying to validate at my job. I will ask coworkers what the process would be for updating to 1.1, but usually there's a whole standards process and everything